# measuring speed of a system call

Tags: linux, performance, system-calls

I am trying to optimize our gettimeofday() system call on Redhat Linux. 
By their documentation it can be speed by running the call in the user land using virtual dynamic shared object (VDSO). I was curious how can I mesure the speed of the call in the first place? I would like to make the change and then compare it against my previous results

Comment: I don't understand how a system call can be run in userspace, or what you can do to substantially optimize it...? My understanding is that the VDSO is just so that the kernel can expose the preferred way of running a system call on the current processor (using `int 80h` or `sysenter`/`syscall`), and keep track of a few other housekeeping details.

Comment: There is a Virtual Dynamic Shared Object (VDSO) implemented in the glibc runtime library.
The VDSO maps some of the kernel code, which is necessary to read gettimeofday in the
user-space. Standard Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.1 allows the gettimeofday function to be
performed entirely in user-space, removing the system call overhead.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely interesting - I'd thought of this possibility, but didn't realize it was actually done. It seems that the kernel stores the processor's time-stamp counter (RDTSC) and the time of day in the VDSO page when a context switch occurs, and this lets glibc compute the time of day without actually doing a system call.

Answer (score 7):

Pseudocode:

1. call `gettimeofday()` and save result in `a`
2. call `gettimeofday()` a million times
3. call `gettimeofday()` and save result in `b`
4. Calculate `(b-a)/1,000,000`

Rationale: The two bounding calls to `gettimeofday()` should not make much of an impact on the loop. It may feel strange to call the function that you want to time but that's OK.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

```
strace -T
```

Answer (score 1):

If your on an Intel platform, [IAPerf.H](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/portable-performance-measurement-macros-for-intel-architecture/) has some macros which make high resolution timing straightforward.

```
   PERFINITMHZ(1200) // Set the clockspeed of your processor
   PERFSTART
   gettimeofday();
   PERFSTOP
   PERFREPORT
```

It's using the [Time Stamp Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) to get the time so you avoid the cost of a sys call and get accurate timing. You may still want to call gettimeofday a million times and divide the result if the results aren't accruate enough.